# Huge difference in number classes loaded into memory by Jetty 8 and Jetty 9

Tags: webserver, jetty, classloader, jetty-8, jetty-9

I am running jetty-distribution-8.1.5.v20120716 and jetty-distribution-9.1.2.v20140210 on a windows 7 machine.

And i find that with Jetty 9 the number of classes loaded into memory are a lot more than the number of classes loaded by Jetty 8 especially after the web app has been deployed.

The web application is developed using Spring 3.X and Hibernate 4.1.X, just in case that could have a effect on things

Below are the numbers i have observed, this causes my first request to be responded slowly, and more over i am just curious to know why this happens

In case you are not able to download Jetty 8 you can download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w3nlsmypq5n61ps/bJCC5WrtjG)

PFA images of my JConsole showing the number of classes loaded in each case

### Jetty 8

Without web app  --                  ~1630

With web app after login      --    ~1632

---

---

### Jetty 9

Without web app --  ~2107 classes

With web app -- ~8700 classes to begin with, and once i access the web application it increases to around ~ 9600 on first request, subsequent requests do not see a spike

**Jetty 8 Without WebApp**
[image: Jetty 8 Without WebApp]

**Jetty 8 With WebApp**
[image: Jetty 8 With WebApp]

**Jetty 9 Without WebApp**
[image: Jetty 9 Without WebApp]

**Jetty 9 With WebApp**
[image: Jetty 9 With WebApp]

Comment: I'm not super-familiar with the Jetty codebase, but I've used it in a few projects and from what I know (and it even shows a bit just reading some of their main pages: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/about.php) they've done quite a bit of refactoring from version to version.  So my guess on this would be the obvious answer: Jetty 9 has a lot more classes.

Comment: One other note: "Below are the numbers i have observed, this causes my first request to be responded slowly..."  It's not a given that the proliferation of classes is your problem - it might just be that Jetty 9 in your particular configuration has performance behavior that causes it to be slower on the first request and then after that things are cached, etc.  The Java JIT in general has this characteristic - that's kinda the way Java is.

Comment: I agree, the reason i say that my first request is slower because of the class loading is that ... i enabled classloading trace and saw that around a 1000 classes get loaded on first request , Second request onwards no classes are loaded and response time is better ... JIT optimization should take a lot longer